# Does or Do? (This is a dissertation’s initial research question)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english

How does Russia’s soft and hard power strategies impact on Georgia’s current political, social and economic environment under the rule of the Georgian Dream government?

Comment: Please cite the source.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the subject is 'strategies'. 
Statement form:  "Russia's soft and hard power strategies impact... (= do impact)
In question form: Do...they....impact?  How do.....impact?